# Present a complex number in rectangular form. I did the right thing? $ \left({\frac{(\sqrt 2 - i\sqrt2)(1-\sqrt3)}{4}}\right)^{28}$

Tags: complex-numbers

1) 
$$\left({\frac{(\sqrt 2 - i\sqrt2)(1-\sqrt3)}{4}}\right)^{28} = \left(\frac{(\sqrt2 -\sqrt6)+i(-\sqrt6-\sqrt2)}{4}\right)^{28} = \left(\frac{\sqrt2-\sqrt6}{4}+\frac{i(-\sqrt6-\sqrt2)}{4}\right)^{28} $$
2) Continue using the formula Moivre 
$$ z^n = |z|^n(\cos{(n\phi)}+i\sin{(n\phi)}) $$
$$|z| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{\sqrt2-\sqrt6}{4}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{-\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{4}\right)^2 } \\= \sqrt{\frac{2-2\sqrt{12}+6}{16}+\frac{6+2\sqrt{12}+2}{16}} \\= \sqrt{\frac{2-2\sqrt{12}+6+6+2\sqrt{12}+2}{16}} = \sqrt{\frac{16}{16}} = 1 $$
3)
$$\tan(\phi) = \frac{-\sqrt6-\sqrt2}{\sqrt2-\sqrt6} = \frac{(-\sqrt6-\sqrt2)(\sqrt2+\sqrt6)}{2-6} = \frac{-(\sqrt2+\sqrt6)(\sqrt2+\sqrt6)}{-4} = \frac{-(2+2\sqrt{12}+6)}{-4} = \frac{-8-2\sqrt{12}}{-4}= \frac{-4(2+\sqrt3)}{-4} = 2 +\sqrt3$$

$$ \phi = \arctan{(2+\sqrt3)} $$

Result:

$$ z = 1^{28} \cdot (\cos(28\arctan(2+\sqrt3) + i\sin(28\arctan(2+\sqrt3))$$

Comment: Is there a typo in the question: should it be $1 - \color{red}{i}\sqrt{3}$ instead of $1-\sqrt{3}$? I'm just guessing based on getting a more 'naturally looking' answer (a complex number of modulus $1$).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that a factor $i$ is missing in front of $\sqrt{3}$.

We use the exponential notation (or just read $e^{it}$ as $\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$ if you are going to use De Moivre Formula) and we split the work in two:
$$(\sqrt 2 - i\sqrt2)^{28}=(2e^{-i\pi/4})^{28}=2^{28}e^{-7i\pi}=-2^{28}$$
and
$$(1 - i\sqrt3)^{28}=(2e^{-i\pi/3})^{28}=2^{28}e^{-28i\pi/3}=2^{28}e^{-4i\pi/3}.$$
Hence
$$\left({\frac{(\sqrt 2 - i\sqrt2)(1-i\sqrt3)}{4}}\right)^{28}=
\frac{-2^{28}\cdot2^{28}e^{-4i\pi/3}}{4^{28}}=-e^{-4i\pi/3}=e^{-i\pi/3}=\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

Comment: @Winther Ops, you are right! Is it a typo?

Comment: teacher said to solve it through the formula Moivre.

Comment: @Frip I am worried about the missing $i$ because $(1-\sqrt{3})^{28}=
833020346368-480944521216\sqrt{3}$...

Comment: @Frip Exponential and De Moivre are similar. Just read $e^{it}$ as $\cos(t)+i\sin(t)$.

Comment: @Frip Does the textbook give an answer for this exercise?